# Auditing Tables in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We want to maintain auditing of tables ,
For that my question is 
1)will the commit interval in Informatica will be stored anywhere in any variable ,
so that we can maintain the record count for every commit interval.

2)is there any method/script to read the stats from session log and save in audit table.

3)If there are multiple targets in my mapping then in monitor after executing it will show target success count and target reject count as total for all the targets in the mapping.
how to get individual target success and reject count .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use informatica metadata tables which informatica doesn't recommend(still I am mentioning for your reference). So your options are to create a sh/bat script to get these info from session log or create a maplet that collects this kind of statistics and add that maplet in every infa mappings. To answers your questions -

1. Yes, commit intervals stored in informatica table opb_task_attr where attr_id=14 and select attr_value.
2. Nope, either you can use some infa mapplet to collct such stats or some shell script.
3. Yes this is possible. use infomatica view rep_sess_tbl_log for this purpose. Here you can get each target's statistics of a particular session's run.

Koushik